# CSS: Make width match dynamic height

Tags: css

I am looking for a pure CSS solution to the given problem.

I need to make a square with x% height of its parent.

This means that the width must match its height.

I have only yet found solutions using JavaScript.

```
.parent{
    height: 60vh;
}

.square{
    height: 90%;
    width: (same as height)
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming your code is for demo purposes because this could be done with `calc` *in this instance*. But no, CSS does not have a mechanism for this...you need JS.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I know to achieve this is quite hacky.

You need to add another child to the child, and this needs to be an image, that has an intrinsic ratio.

If the image is square, then the child will be square.

The image is not showing, we just need it to be there, so I set opacity to 0.

```css
.father {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.child {
  border: solid 1px blue;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 90%;
  width: fit-content;
}

.child img {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="father">
  <div class="child">
     <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/04i18.png">
  </div>
</div>
```